# LINQ Query returns proper count but duplicates data

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

[image]

I have the below query which brings the position value. 
If I run the SQL query obtained from the debug window the records look okay.
But the list doesn't seem to duplicate the value for Report Date field in c#.

```
var query = (from AceBi in context.AceBiMonthlyDaos 
join Inst in context.Instruments on AceBi.Naid equals Inst.AceId 
join FinAcct in context.FinancialAccounts on AceBi.PositionAccountKey equals 
FinAcct.AceClientId where AceBi.PositionAccountKey != null 
join Invst in context.Investments   
on new { a = Inst.Id, b = FinAcct.Id} equals new { a = Invst.InstrumentId, b = Invst.FinAcctId }
select new { AceBi, Invst}).Distinct();
```

Output from SQL image 1
Output list in Entity image 2

[image]

Comment: As you can see, the output in the list has duplicated report date value or it just picks the first reportdate value for all 3 records related to na_id/aceclientid pair

Comment: Esp. the second list as image is extremely hard to read. Therefore it's always discouraged to use screenshots of textual output in questions. You better paste the text itself, formatted properly. That said, duplicated data always has to do with non-unique primary keys in the EF class model.

Answer (score 0):

try convert it to dictionary first

```
Dictionary<int, DateTime> existingItems = 
(from ObjType ot in TableObj).ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
```